# LTC6102 - transient response, error of the simulator?

Tags: current-measurement

i'm building a device that has to measure current high side for 3 different scales: 1uA to 1mA, 1mA to 1A, 1A to 10A.

what i'm doing is to use a current sense amplifier from Analog devices - LTC6102 (https://ro.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/6102fe-1279477.pdf) and three different shunts for every scale: 500 ohm for uA scale, 0.5 ohm for mA scale and 0.05 ohm for A scale and a gain=10 (R3/R2).

in order to comute from one scale to another i'm using DPST relays (to minimise the error of reading due to voltage drop across contacts).

during simulations i observed something strange:
when i connect the device to supply there is an output current spike that is over the limit of output current.
my question is if i miss something in designing of the circuit or the LTspice is playing with me :( .. ?

to be more clear what I did is:

[image]

look what happens when i bring supply voltage to 12V and i commute the relay (this happening with a delay of 10ms):
[image]

there is that spike of voltage that is clamped by that schottky diode.

i thought that there is a problem if i don't connect the input terminals of LTC6102 ... i tried to disconnect one of the terminals:
[image]

[image]

hmm ... maybe is because the PMOS (inside LTC6102) is going into ohmic region ... let's see what's happening if i will not allow this thing by setting relays to be closed when the circuit will be supplyed ... but the spike is still there!!
[image]

i would really appreciate some feedback!!
thx ;p